# How to index partition field?

Tags: playorm

I have an entity (Request) which is partitioned by userId. For each userId, I will have an index, right?

However, I would like to quickly search the request by userId. Is there a simple way to do that? Or I will need to choose another field to create the partition?

Comment: Sorry, I meant find all the requests related to that userId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition TWO ways if you like.  Let's say you do this

```
public class Request {
    @NoSqlId
    @NoSqlIndexed
    private String uniqueId;

    @NoSqlIndexed
    @NoSqlPartitionedBy
    @NoSqlManyToOne
    private User user;

    @NoSqlIndexed
    @NoSqlPartitionedBy
    private LocalDate beginningOfEachMonth;
}
```

You can have private String userId instead of User if you like ;).

Now, you can query into a time partition using the beginning of the month as a key and just do a query OR you can query into a user partition using user as the key.

Your named query IF you partition by two things would be...

```
query="PARTITIONS("user", :user) SELECT r FROM TABLE as r"
```

If you only partition your table by users, you can write

```
query="PARTITIONS(:user) SELECT r FROM TABLE as r"
```

NOTE: The only reason you sometimes need to index the primary key like I have is for a range query on the primary key....for an equals query where pk= some value, you don't need an index obviously since you can look up by the primary key itself.

Dean